# Why is my constructor is undefined even though I have made a constructor in another class?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to create a few dummy data in TaskApplication.java by using Task(). For some reason it says that the constructor Task() is undefined eventhough i have defined it in my Task.java class and have imported that package into my TaskApplication.java.'

Here's my code:
TaskApplication.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TasksApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TasksApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner runner(TaskService taskService) {
        return args -> {
            taskService.save(new Task(1L, "Create Spring Boot Application", LocalDate.now(), true));
            taskService.save( new Task(2L,"Create Spring Project Packages", LocalDate.now().plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS), false));
            taskService.save( new Task(3L,"Create the Task Domain Class", LocalDate.now().plus(3,ChronoUnit.DAYS), false));
            taskService.save( new Task(4L,"Create service and repository classes", LocalDate.now().plus(5,ChronoUnit.DAYS), false));
            taskService.save( new Task(5L,"Create the command line runner to load data", LocalDate.now().plus(8, ChronoUnit.DAYS), false));
            taskService.save( new Task(6L,"Create the required configuration properties", LocalDate.now().plus(10,ChronoUnit.DAYS), false));
            taskService.save( new Task(7L,"Run the Spring Boot Application", LocalDate.now().plus(12,ChronoUnit.DAYS), false));
            taskService.save( new Task(8L,"Check the H2 Console for the initial data", LocalDate.now().plus(13,ChronoUnit.DAYS), false));
        };
    }
}
```

Task.java:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
    private LocalDate dueDate;
    private Boolean completed;

    public Task() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix annotation based constructor and programmatic constructor. If you want add default constructor with out argument then use this `@NoArgsConstructor`

Comment: I've actually tried doing that, but it doesn't solve the problem for some reason

Answer (score 0):

As a note - I would also specify you are using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org) for the annotations.

This is most likely an issue with your `@JsonFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")`
on top of the LocalDate. There isn't a constructor that is converting the object to that string pattern. Can you try writing a constructor without the `@AllArgsConstructor` and see if that works?